# Instruments leaks stopping after app starts

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, instruments, memory-leaks

So I want use Leaks to find the leaks in my app. In Xcode, I go to "Product" and then hit "Profile". In Instruments I select Leaks and it starts.
My app is starting and Leaks is running. But just as soon as my app is finished starting and I can use it, Leaks stops.

Is there anybody else with the same problem or maybe knows how to fix this?

Comment: Hm.. It should work fine. Do you still have the problem ?

Comment: Yes, but sometimes, like 1 out of 8, it does work. Yet my app launches normally every time.

Comment: That's probably a bug that's not your fault. A nasty bug.

Comment: I've been doing a bunch of searching on this and there are various mentions in various places indicating that it's not unique but not very helpful in terms of a fix or workaround. I've replicated it in both XC3.2.6 and XC4.0.2 but I'm not sure if it's only started since I loaded 4.2. I removed 4.2, but you never know what else it changed when it installed that didn't get reverted.

Comment: Curious about what devices/sdks you've seen this on. In limited testing, I've only seen it on an iPad 2 running 4.3.3. I haven't seen it on an iPhone 4 running 4.3.3 or an iPad 1 running 4.3.2.

Comment: I've tested my app with an iPad 2 (4.3.2), where Leaks stops. I also tested it with an iPad 1 (4.2.1) and it works normally. I haven't tested it on an iPhone though.

Comment: i have same problem. have any solution ? my app is okay. but won't start in instrument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen this happen when an incorrect provisioning profile is used when building the app and running on a physical device.

You shouldn't see this kind of error when running it in the simulator - it should work as intended. If you're using the simulator in this situation and are you still seeing this behaviour, I would encourage you to go to http://bugreport.apple.com and file a bug regarding this issue, *giving as much detail as you possibly can*.

If you're using a physical device, ensure you're using a valid provisioning profile and certificate/key pair and that the device is included in the profile.

Answer (score 1):

clean project build folder, close XCode IDE and clean MAC Os caches then it should work. if it's an iOS project you have to delete app from simulator/device before re compile it.

Answer (score 1):

I would chose a development profile for all release,debug modes, clean the simulator, clean xcode ,then i would launch instruments

Answer (score 1):

The Leaks instrument seems to close after the app receives lot of memory warnings. Closing all background applications helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Cocoapods, be sure, you have unchecked `Run script only when installing` in Target > Build Phases > [CP] Embedded Pods Framework. Checked this option caused same problem for me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That was my case.
If you're using a real device, make sure you're using a valid provisioning profile (development provisioning profile) and that the device is included in the profile. [More detailed explanation here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45421179/xcode-beta-error-iphone-has-denied-the-launch-request)