# Missing App Identifier and Access Keychain Groups on every machine

Tags: ios, code-signing, provisioning-profile, apple-developer, code-signing-entitlements

Since from today morning, I am getting these two errors while building it on device: -

1. List item

Automatic signing is unable to resolve an issue with the "AppName" target's entitlements.

1. List item

Provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: com.xxx.yyssnn" doesn't include the application-identifier and keychain-access-groups entitlements.

Tried with multiple Team Accounts and on different machines but no luck. Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check your certificates removed/expired in both keychain access and developer account.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Provisioning profile doesn't include the application-identifier and keychain-access-groups entitlements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55132628/provisioning-profile-doesnt-include-the-application-identifier-and-keychain-acc)

Comment: Apple Server outage is most probably the issue.

Comment: Any luck? Still having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem this morning. I write how I solved with the hope that it works for you too. With the project open, click on the project file and then in the next column, on ***Target -> Capabilities*** and activate ***App Groups*** and ***Keychain Sharing***. Now in the project navigator column a file ***nameProject.entitlements*** will appear, move ***nameProject.entitlements*** out of the folder, always in the project navigator just below the project file. Always in ***Capabilities*** put ***off*** again: ***App Groups*** and ***Keychain Sharing***. Now click on ***Project -> Build Settings -> Signing -> Code Signing Identity*** and ***select: iPhone Developer:*** .... A little further up in ***Code Signing Entitlements***: double click on the text field to its right and copy (or write) ***to integer the name of the file nameProject.entitlements and click enter***. Now it should work, I hope it helps.

Comment: i didn't see Code Signing Entitlements.. is it in Build Settings too?

Comment: Hi @miracle-doh, as Lets Code said, Code Signing Entitlements is in Build Settings. If you don't see it, select **All** in Build Settings, instead of **Basic**. :)