# Xcode 10.1 failed to create provisioning profile after trying to side load app to device w/ iOS 12.1

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-provisioning

Three errors under General that I can't figure out:

- Failed to create provisioning profile: The app ID '' cannot be registered to your development team. Change your bundle identifier to a unique string to try again.
- Provisioning profile doesn't support the Keychain Sharing capability
- Provisioning profile doesn't include the keychain-access-groups entitlement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an Apple issue, you can see a master thread discussing it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55132628/provisioning-profile-doesnt-include-the-application-identifier-and-keychain-acc).

The root of the problem is simply XCode not generating the entitlements file which your project requires. I've outlined the steps on how to figure it out in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55146587/automatic-signing-is-unable-to-resolve-an-issue-with-the-project-targets-enti/55152333#55152333). Let me know if it works for you!