# Xcode Automatic sign in and provisioning profile errors

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to run my iOS app on TestFlight. the app runs on the simulator but when I connect it to my iPhone and try to run it, the ffollowing error shows up.
Automatic signing failed
Xcode failed to provision this target. Please file a bug report at https://bugreport.apple.com/ and include the Update Signing report from the Report navigator.

Provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: com.uditi.clima" doesn't support the Keychain Sharing capability.

Provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: com.uditi.clima" doesn't include the keychain-access-groups entitlement.

I tried to change my bundle identifier. I am new to iOS Dev and not sure how things work. [error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFH4a.png)

I switched on keychain sharing but an error appears - Automatic sign in failed

Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate. Check this out: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55132628/provisioning-profile-doesnt-include-the-application-identifier-and-keychain-acc)

Comment: I only restart my laptop and tried again, this works for me!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is due to some certification issues over at Apple, but in the meantime here's a workaround:

1. Open the project in Xcode. Select the project from the Project Navigator, then select your Target from the column.
2. Click on the General tab, and under the Signing section, enable "Automatically manage signing".
3. Next, click on the Capabilities tab and make sure both "Keychain Sharing" and "App Groups" are switched to "On". Ignore any error messages.
4. An entitlements file will be generated in the Project Navigator. The file is recognizable by its extension `.entitlements`.
5. Move the `.entitlements` file to the root folder by dragging it until it's right underneath the project file.
6. Now, back in the "Capabilities" tab, turn off "Keychain Sharing" and "App Groups". Ignore any error messages.
7. Select the project and go to its "Build Settings" tab. Directly beneath the tab, select both "All" and "Combined". Scroll down (or use the search, upper right) to find the "Code Signing Identity" section and change all of the options to `iOS Developer`.
8. Next, scroll to (or search for) the "Code Signing Entitlements" section. Double click the text field next to "Code Signing Entitlements" and type in the entire name of the `.entitlements` file you moved before. For example, `HelloWorld.entitlements`.

This should solve the provisioning error until Apple addresses these certification issues.

Comment: Somehow this helped me in 2019. Thank you!

Comment: Cannot find a "Capabilities tab".

Answer (score 3):

if u want to use your m1 mac as phone:
Are you maybe running Xcode in Rosetta mode? I had this issue, exactly as mentioned above. To fix this I closed Xcode, turned off Rosetta and it's now working as expected.

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/676083

Comment: nice one. really helpful

Answer (score 2):

Just change Trust to System default on Developer ID Certification Authority

Comment: this is the only one that works for me

Comment: @Nikola Arsovski how do you change Trust to System default  , i did not get your point , will you please let me know in detail how you change this

Answer (score 0):

Recently I faced the exact same problem,
Searched a lot with no success on the way others suggested.

I have found a work around by just removing every single capability below signing... like app group, network extension, keychain sharing, etc... I just remove everything below signing and then add them again right away then all error gone with a successful build.

Answer (score 0):

Reboot of my laptop fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

In my particular case, for a similar but slightly different issue, I have a widget in my project and had included the App Attest capability in the main app. The main app target and the widget were sharing an `.entitlements` file in Build Settings, and this was causing provisioning to fail for the widget since widgets don't have an App Attest capability.

Just posting in case that happens to help someone else stumbling across this looking for a solution to a similar problem.