# Is receiving SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed in the sandbox despite a success alert considered okay?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

I'm doing some testing around IAP on a device. Purchases normally work, however today I'm getting an interesting behavior that I haven't seen before.

When I make the purchase, I receive a

> You're all set. Your purchase was successful. [Environment: Sandbox]

alert.

However, I am getting a transaction state of `SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed` with the error

> Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to iTunes Store}

On the one hand this was fortuitous in that I discovered I was accidentally calling `finishTransaction`. On the other hand, it is bit weird to see the alert which indicates the success but yet receive a different type of error from the transaction.

Do I chalk this up to one of the nuances of the sandbox? Or can something like this happen in prod too?

What is interesting about this is it seems then there are 2 different mechanisms underneath.

I do plan on creating a bug report for this with Apple.

Comment: I find the sandbox quite an unreliable way to test. The whole process of in app purchase is pretty indeterminate.

Comment: @matt sigh, agreed. I've worked on a bunch of IAP in iOS. I just don't recall anything like this happening. I think I would have remembered QA being in an uproar over something like.

Comment: Hmmm see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55158357/swift-inapp-purchase-fails-but-system-dialog-say-youre-all-set I think the whole store purchase mechanism has broken down suddenly.

Comment: Possibly related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55132628/provisioning-profile-doesnt-include-the-application-identifier-and-keychain-acc/55152736#55152736

Comment: This seems to be a widespread issue in Sandbox right now: https://twitter.com/RevenueCat/status/1106235357413036032

Comment: @matt thanks for the follow up! I also did open a bug report with Apple. Mainly because it seems odd that 2 parts of their system think the results are different.