# Xcode 10.1 iPhone has denied the launch request

Tags: ios, xcode

My XCode suddenly cannot run the debug mode today and show "iPhone has denied the launch request". I search all inforamtion. The following things I have already tried.

1. My original setting is automatically manage signing
2. I have already tried to remove all certification
3. All certification set to system default
4. I need to debug the program so I cannot turn off the "debug executable"
5. Restart iPhone and computer
6. Create new project but the problem is still here.

Can anyone help me?  My ios version is 12.1.4

Comment: Create a new blank project and check still same is happening or not?

Comment: @dahiya_boy Yes, I have also tried

Comment: May be the same as this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45421179/xcode-9-error-iphone-has-denied-the-launch-request

Comment: It is also related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55132628/provisioning-profile-doesnt-include-the-application-identifier-and-keychain-acc

Comment: All part of the same mess at Apple’s end. You just have to wait for them to fix it.

Comment: I saw some people said apple solved the problem. I still encounter the error.