# Unable to upload app to App Store connect

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app-store-connect

I am trying to upload my app to the App Store connect but I'm not able to.

I was testing my app using Xcode 12 and without realising it was beta software, I archived my app and uploaded it. Now when I click on submit for review it says Binary Invalid. Then, I realized that I wasn't supposed to upload it using Xcode beta. Now, when I try uploading it with Xcode 11.5, It isn't letting me sign the app as I get an error saying `Profile doesn’t include the com.apple.application-identifier entitlement` .
I have tried the following Methods and none seem to work.

1. Close Xcode and Delete all provisional Files from `~/Library/ApplicationSupport/MobileProvisions/`

2.Change the Bundle ID and also tried repeating (1.)

3. Create new certificates and profiles from the developer website(Both original and new bundle IDs)
4. Delete Xcode and reinstall it.

But in the end it only uploads it with Xcode 12 beta. (And throws an error saying Binary Invalid)

Please help me rectify this issue.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/650438 also this could help you : https://stackoverflow.com/q/55132628/2323806

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I struggled with this problem for two days, simple fix is to;

Build with 11.5
Archive / Upload with 12 beta

Comment: Some basic guidelines can be found here https://www.whatmattered.com/publishing-mobile-apps-on-app-store-google-play/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer. Create your archive. In the organizer, select your archive. Choose distribute app. Then instead of upload, choose **export**. Export the archive to a folder on your hard drive. Now download transporter from the App Store. Transporter replaced "Application Loader" or whatever it used to be called in the developer tools menu of Xcode.
Now sign into Transporter with your dev account and upload the .ipa found in your exported archive folder using Transporter.
It will work under Big Sur!