# IOS Native not Run on real device

Tags: ios, xcode

I can't run my native IOS apps on my  device after updated my Xcode to Version 10.1 (10B61) Error is  "iPhone has denied the launch request.", anyone can helpme ?

Comment: Try after force quitting the Xcode and re-attaching the device.

Comment: not worked, message error, "Could not launch myApp, Iphone as denied the launch request" .

Comment: Are you using the paid account or free account?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS 12 iPad Denied Launch Request - Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52415694/ios-12-ipad-denied-launch-request-xcode)

Comment: I am working with a Free account .

Answer (score 0):

Re-run the project. If it doesn't work, restart Xcode then run the project. Make sure your device is connected and your team account is set.