# Xcode 10: Provisioning Profile has get-task-allow false resulting in "iPhone has denied the launch request"

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing-certificate

I have a free Apple Developer account (just an Apple ID).
Hence, I can only use automatic signing in Xcode.

I'm trying to build/ run an app on my iPhone 7. 
Everything worked previously and all of a sudden I can't seem to get it to work.
I tried everything from this [related question for Xcode 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45421179/xcode-9-error-iphone-has-denied-the-launch-request) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52415694/ios-12-ipad-denied-launch-request-xcode)

While I got the app itself to work, if I uncheck `Debug executable` in the my scheme, I cannot seem to get it to debug.
After reading up, I realized the provisioning profile has `get-task-allow` set to `false`. While this is fine for distribution profiles, I'm running everything under my developer profile. 
Is anyone else facing this issue? What is my recourse here?
[image]

Deleting Apple Worldwide Developer Certificates or creating a new user don't address the underlying issue. It seems like the correct entitlements are not getting passed to the provisioning profile.

Comment: @Paulw11 this isn't a duplicate. The underlying issues aren't addressed in the other question

Comment: All part of the ongoing mess at Apple’s end.