# Xcode Unable to launch app on real device

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to run my Xcode project (exported from Unity directly) on my iphone.

The project was installed on the device successfully (I can see the app on my phone), but unable to launch.

I got the below error message without any further instructions:

[image]

I've done below instructions but still fail to launch:

1. Trust my Apple Developer ID on the device
2. Delete the `Apple WorldWide ...` certificate in Keychain
3. `Product` -> `Edit Scheme` -> `Run` -> `Executable` -> `Ask on launch`
4. `Product` -> `Edit Scheme` -> `Info` -> `debug executable` -> unchecked
5. Make sure the deployment target is the same version as my phone
6. `Build Settings` -> `Mach-O type` -> `Bundle`
7. Clean project, restart XCode, unplug & restart my phone

Comment: Did you import Some files from other projects, like storyboard/Classes and some other stuff?

Comment: @MuhammadDanishQureshi No, I just run the project exported from Unity without making any changes.

Comment: So thats why its saying like this.... You exported whole project... and Xcode says it when ever we copy a Storyboard from other project...! Its Xcode bug...!

Comment: @MuhammadDanishQureshi but I followed this tutorial https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/mobile-touch/building-your-unity-game-ios-device-testing from Unity, seems like it should be fine simply open the exported project

Comment: try this.. `Product` -> `Edit Scheme` -> `Run` -> `Info` -> `Release` and `debug executable -> unchecked`

Comment: @NiravKotecha I tried it, not work :(

Comment: @VanessaLeung this tutorial is almost 4 years old...! Maybe this bug is occurring in new versions of Xcode...! There is a hook in my mind...! try it...!
change your bundle identifier name and then clean and build.

Comment: @MuhammadDanishQureshi still not working :(

Comment: @VanessaLeung hows your project complexity...? I mean how much storyboards are there in it...? I will advise you to make storyboard in Xcode...! and get classes from your previous project...!
*Important*: Keep in mind when you make an outlet from storyboard then must check how much things are attached with that outlet..! Mostly in these cases (import/export projects) outlets keep reference more than 1 projects.
If it's keep only 1 thing reference than it will must work for you.

Comment: @VanessaLeung What happens when you do Edit Scheme > Run > Executable > Launch Automatically? All my Xcode projects are set that way, and I've never had a problem launching on an iOS device. Asking for the executable on launch may be your problem.

Comment: @MarkSzymczyk because I first got the error `iphone has denied the launch request`, so I followed [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53676140/8078036) to solve this error, but then got the error `Unable to launch app on real device`