# iPhone has denied the launch request Xcode 10 + Cordova

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cordova

I have built a Cordova app, I've recently been able to build the app and run it on my phone prior to adding a new paid Apple Developer account to Xcode (not a Personal Team account).

Since adding this account, I am encountering the issue where the app will successfully build, but won't launch on the iPhone, it will continuously close every time I tap the app icon, in addition the error I get in Xcode is:

```
iPhone has denied the launch request.
Internal launch error: process launch failed: Unspecified
```

I'm running Xcode 10.2.1, building to an iPhone 6S Plus running iOS 12.4 (the latest), and am using Cordova 8.0.0

I've tried deleting the Apple Worldwide certificate, adding a new account, adding a new user to the system, restarting the machine, changing the Bundle Identifier.

Inside of the signing tab in general I have:

Team: [name of team]
Provisioning Profile: Xcode Managed Profile
Signing Certificate: iPhone Developer: [name of person] ([some ID])

In addition, I have currently got the following command: `cordova run ios --buildFlag='-UseModernBuildSystem=0'`

But the build system shouldn't matter here.

**EDIT**

Updating to Xcode 10.3 doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52415694/ios-12-ipad-denied-launch-request-xcode/52584195#52584195

Comment: This doesn't fix it for me unfortunately