# Nativescript: crash at launch of iOS Application in device

Tags: ios, angular, xcode, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

After update Xcode to 10 version and iOS 12 in device, i have a problem with ios app generate by Nativescript:

- with the emulator, the app run correctly;
- with the device, the build is ok, but the app crash without error when the app is opening at splash screen. The same if i use Xcode;
- when i archive the app with Xcode, upload to TestFlight correctly.

The trid to change certificates, but I have the same problem. I use 4.2.3 version of Nativescript (i tried 5.0.0 -next-).

Comment: Assuming you are trying release build on device, did you try running the app with `--bundle` option in Simulator, still works?

Comment: @Manoj in simulator, app works, i have a problem only in physical device ...

Comment: What commands you used exactly for Simulator and Device?

Comment: are you using webview by any chance in your app or making any external URL call at initilaization ?

Comment: @Manoj "tns run ios" or "tns run ios --bundle --env.uglify --env.aot"

Comment: @Narendra i make a http request at initilaization, but if i upload app in testflight, it works correctly, only if i make "tns run ios" it not works

Comment: I resolve! i follow this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52440492/ios-app-wont-run-on-device-any-more-under-ios-12-unrecoverable-ct-signature-is/52506186#52506186

Answer (score 1):

If you use any NS plugin in your app,check its pods. 
If any pod is deprecated ; review changes on cocoapods pages of pods or git repo of plugin

Comment: but why i can upload app in testflight and it works correctly? Only if i do "tns run ios" it don't works

Comment: Simulator iOS version - your iPhone iOS version? They are same?

Comment: Yes. In simulator app works, upload and execute from testflight ok, but not work only if i run app from xcode or prompt (tns run ios)

Comment: I see. Did you try ‘tns platform remove ios’ and add again?

Comment: How can I check your app?

Answer (score 0):

You should use Nativescript Sidekick to build and run release app.
Then in Xcode choose Generic Device > Analyze > Archive > Upload.

If the error still occurs, remove platforms ios, node_modules then rebuild app.