# Xcode: iOS app suddenly always crashes on launch

Tags: ios, xcode, crash

I created a quite simple app that can receive push notifications and display content. This is working without any problems since month.

Since yesterday the app suddenly crashes every time I want to launch it.

I'm using an iPhone 8 Plus with iOS 12.4.1. Restarting the app, hard and soft reset of the iPhone didn't help.

The console says the following:

> fehler    07:37:35.510970 +0200   assertiond  Unable to obtain a task name
>   port right for pid 542: (os/kern) failure (0x5)
>
> fehler    07:37:35.511100 +0200   assertiond  Failed to start job with error
>    {
>       description = "Unable to get valid task name port right for pid 542";
>       failureReason = "The process failed to exec";
>       recoverySuggestion = "Consult /var/log/com.apple.xpc.launchd/launchd.log for more information"; }
>
> fehler    07:37:35.511894 +0200   SpringBoard [MyCompany.MyApp] Bootstrap
>   failed with error:
>
> fehler    07:37:35.512091 +0200   SpringBoard Bootstrapping failed for
>    with
>   error: Error Domain=BKSProcessErrorDomain Code=1 "Unable to bootstrap
>   process with bundleID MyCompany.MyApp"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to bootstrap process with
>   bundleID MyCompany.MyApp, BKSProcessExitReason=0,
>   NSLocalizedFailureReason=Failed to start job,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x28146e760 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=3
>   "No such process" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The process
>   failed to exec, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Consult
>   /var/log/com.apple.xpc.launchd/launchd.log for more information,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to get valid task name port right for
>   pid 542}}, BSErrorCodeDescription=bootstrap-failed}

Does anybody have an idea why my app is suddenly crashing?

Comment: try to Delete and reinstall the app.

Comment: @manishsharma93 Yes, sure, that worked. But this shouldn't even happen. What if it's an app published in the App Store?

Comment: Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52440492/ios-app-wont-run-on-device-any-more-under-ios-12-unrecoverable-ct-signature-is).

Comment: @David You might have installed this app through some URL provided to you(via diawi or some other). This thing happens after some time. Don't know the exact reason. Can assure you the thing that this will not happen once your app is published in the App Store.

Comment: @manishsharma93 No, I build the app in Xcode myself and installed it on my iPhone directly via cable.

Answer (score 0):

It might be happening if the developer certificate you used to create this app has been revoked or another app (still in development mode) with same bundle identifier is using your developer certificates. It happens when we build apps for testing purpose with free developer account which shares the certificate identities.

Comment: I'm using a paid Apple Developer Account.This is the only app I use with this bundle identifier. This problem appeared yesterday. I didn't even open Apple Developer Account or Xcode since weeks, so I also didn't make any changes. But I'm using the app every day multiple times. After reinstalling the app, everything is working. This means, that there's nothing with the developer certificate.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my iPhone. It stopped working after a few days, so I checked around to see if I could find an answer. I found this, and it worked for me:

> "Without enrolling in the Apple Developer Program, your app will only
>   last for 7 days on your device. After that, you’ll have to re-deploy
>   it to your device via Xcode. If you’re enrolled in the Apple Developer
>   Program, you won’t have this inconvenience."

I know it doesn't apply to the original question since he says he has a developer license, but it would apply to many others who don't pay for a license and if your license have expired.
I'm not sure if it's allowed to post a link to where I found the question, so just take it away if that's the case, but I do like to refer to where I got it from, when it's not me. https://codewithchris.com/deploy-your-app-on-an-iphone/