# Xcode Error , The operation couldn’t be completed. No such process. React Native

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, ios-simulator, apple-m1

I am trying to build my app on iPhone simulator with m1 mac, but I get this error alert from xcode,

"The operation couldn’t be completed. No such process",

Details

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. No such process
Domain: NSPOSIXErrorDomain
Code: 3
Failure Reason: No such process
User Info: {

    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2022-09-15 08:54:55 +0000";

    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDELaunchiPhoneSimulatorLauncher;

}

Analytics Event: com.apple.dt.IDERunOperationWorkerFinished : {

    "device_model" = "iPhone14,2";

    "device_osBuild" = "15.2 (19C51)";

    "device_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphonesimulator";

    "launchSession_schemeCommand" = Run;

    "launchSession_state" = 1;

    "launchSession_targetArch" = arm64;

    "operation_duration_ms" = 2091;

    "operation_errorCode" = 3;

    "operation_errorDomain" = NSPOSIXErrorDomain;

    "operation_errorWorker" = IDELaunchiPhoneSimulatorLauncher;

    "operation_name" = IDERunOperationWorkerGroup;

    "param_consoleMode" = 0;

    "param_debugger_attachToExtensions" = 0;

    "param_debugger_attachToXPC" = 1;

    "param_debugger_type" = 3;

    "param_destination_isProxy" = 0;

    "param_destination_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphonesimulator";

    "param_diag_MainThreadChecker_stopOnIssue" = 0;

    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableDuringAttach" = 0;

    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableForXPC" = 1;

    "param_diag_allowLocationSimulation" = 1;

    "param_diag_gpu_frameCapture_enable" = 0;

    "param_diag_gpu_shaderValidation_enable" = 0;

    "param_diag_gpu_validation_enable" = 0;

    "param_diag_memoryGraphOnResourceException" = 0;

    "param_diag_queueDebugging_enable" = 1;

    "param_diag_runtimeProfile_generate" = 0;

    "param_diag_sanitizer_asan_enable" = 0;

    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_enable" = 0;

    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;

    "param_diag_sanitizer_ubsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;

    "param_diag_showNonLocalizedStrings" = 0;

    "param_diag_viewDebugging_enabled" = 1;

    "param_diag_viewDebugging_insertDylibOnLaunch" = 1;

    "param_install_style" = 0;

    "param_launcher_UID" = 2;

    "param_launcher_allowDeviceSensorReplayData" = 0;

    "param_launcher_kind" = 0;

    "param_launcher_style" = 0;

    "param_launcher_substyle" = 0;

    "param_runnable_appExtensionHostRunMode" = 0;

    "param_runnable_productType" = "com.apple.product-type.application";

    "param_runnable_swiftVersion" = "5.6.1";

    "param_runnable_type" = 2;

    "param_testing_launchedForTesting" = 0;

    "param_testing_suppressSimulatorApp" = 0;

    "param_testing_usingCLI" = 0;

    "sdk_canonicalName" = "iphonesimulator15.5";

    "sdk_osVersion" = "15.5";

    "sdk_variant" = iphonesimulator;

}
```

--

**System Information**

- macOS Version 12.5.1 (Build 21G83)
- Xcode 13.4.1 (20504) (Build 13F100)
- Timestamp: 2022-09-15T10:54:55+02:00

I tried to upgrade IOS version of the app from "ios 10" to "ios 12" but it didn't work

Comment: It's an issue with authorization. Try this in the Terminal:

sudo DevToolsSecurity -enable

Comment: tried `sudo DevToolsSecurity -enable` but it didn't work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52506186/6654562 try this one

Comment: have you fixed it ?