# iPhone has denied the launch request

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Xcode denies the app launch I debug mode. If I edit the scheme to not support debug mode, it will launch the app but I loose the ability to debug. This project has two shemes, release and debug.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45421179/xcode-9-error-iphone-has-denied-the-launch-request

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. In project , open your project's TARGETS.
2. Check your ***Provisioning Profile*** whethe is match ***Signing certificate***
3. In **debug** their are **develop** profile and certificate,and in release their are **distribution** profile and certificate

   if you don't determine, there is a easy way to help you,**xcode** offer the ***Automatically manage signing*** ,just in xocode tick this option.[image: look this here]