# Xcode 10 - iPhone has denied request to launch

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I'm running `Xcode 10` and `iOS 12.1` on my `iPhone 6S Plus`. The app works when running in simulator, but when running my app in `Xcode` with my phone connected, i get this error:

> iPhone has denied the launch request.

[image: error]

My iPhone is a trusted device on my mac, and i have my signing certificate. I've spent hours googling for a solution but none of them are working for me.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Is it happening every time? This usually happens when the app is being opened by Xcode, and at the same time your iPhone gets locked. Try removing the passcode in your device and see if it works.

Comment: Please try to plug out and reconnect the device to Mac and run the project again make sure the device without being locked while the app is installing.

Comment: I have same problem. You find an issue?

Answer (score 10):

I was also facing similar issue.
What work for me is to change the trust to "Use System Defaults" (Previously it was always ask) in "Apple worldwide developer relation certificate authority" in keychain.

[image]

Comment: Thank you—I've been plagued by this issue for a couple of months, and this is the first solution that's worked for me!

Comment: You should get a Nobel prize for this. THANK YOU!!

Answer (score 3):

My solution worked: Menu Xcode - Product - Scheme - Edit scheme - Build Configuration -> [Release] (instead of Debug) + Debug executable -> [remove the cross]

Comment: Nice. It worked. The next step would be to understand what sorcery this is.

Answer (score 3):

I have faced the same issue when I run the build-in ad hoc profile and I have fixed it by unchecking the " Debug executable " option from the Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try upgrading from XCode 10 to XCode 10.1. The SDKs for iOS 12.1 were added in XCode 10.1, so XCode might be having trouble communicating with your device because it's on a higher OS version than it understands.

Answer (score 0):

In project , open your project's TARGETS.

```
1.Check your Provisioning Profile whether is match Signing certificate
2.In debug their are develope profile and certificate,and in release their are distribution profile and certificate
3.[enter link description here][1]if you don't determine, there is a easy way to help you,xcode offer the Automatically manage signing ,just in xocode tick this option.look this here
```

This will help: [iPhone has denied the launch request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52840945/iphone-has-denied-the-launch-request)

Answer (score 0):

Select the Project> Target > Build Settings. Search PROVISIONING_PROFILE and remove whatever is there. Then run.

Answer (score 0):

Check you certificate in keychain  if its double delete one of them > Quit XCODE > Clean > Build again ( This work to me )

Answer (score 0):

edit scheme > uncheck debug executable.....this works but make you lose debug capabilities.

what is really worked for me without losing the debug capabilities is doing the following

1. open keychain
2. search for iphone developer certificate
3. delete it (Xcode will create another one for you)
4. relaunch the app Xcode will ask for your computer password type it and you are done

i found this answer thanks to Tommy Callaway on youtube 
[video link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j1ztHZ8v474)

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to delete ALL my apple dev certs locally, then approve them during the next build process.

But def make sure you've set the provisioning profile for your project, that's a classic..

[Keychain Access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KW1e7.png)

Answer (score 0):

On my device, I went to Settings -> General -> Profiles & Device Management. I then tapped on the 'developer app entry' which displayed my personal development team. On the next screen I chose to trust apps from this developer (me).