# Xcode Version 10.2 problem with running on iphone

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I just updated my Iphone to ios 12.2 and I am getting the following error when I launch the Xcode project:

[image]

I did a bit of Googling and I have already tried...

- editing the scheme
- automatically manage signing

please help I am desperate!

Comment: Restarted your Mac?

Comment: hi @MikeTaverne I solved it there, will post solution now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by:

- going to keychain
- searching for "Iphone Developer"
- right clicking and deleting "Iphone developer"
- xcode will create another when you build
- revoke and still doesnt work so then you have to
- finding "Apple Worldwide Developer relation certificate authority"
- setting the 'trust' (by double clicking) to "Use system defaults"

I completed this by using:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j1ztHZ8v474

and

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53273629/10459255