# once again iphone denying the launch request

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing

So I try to deploy a new application (File - New Project) on my iphone and... And... Nothing... "has denied the launch request". On simulator everything is ok.

Yes, I read this
[Xcode 9 error: "iPhone has denied the launch request"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45421179/xcode-9-error-iphone-has-denied-the-launch-request)

I use 'automatic manage signing' and Signing certificate is 'iPhone Developer...'. Code Signing Identity in Build Settings section set to 'iOS Developer'

I have no idea at all. Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind. Setting 'Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority' trust mode from 'Always trust' to 'System defaults' fixed this issue.

Comment: could u be more thourow in our answer... where do u find  that exetera