# iPhone has denied the launch request Unspecified

Tags: ios, xcode

> iPhone has denied the launch request. Internal launch error: process launch failed: Unspecified

This error is making me crazy and I can't seems to be able to solve it, I have done the following from everywhere I found:

- Refresh cert, signed out and in developer apple account, download manual certificate
- Delete Apple Worldwide Certificate
- Restart both Mac and iPhone
- Clean project, build folder
- Deleted Derived data
- Change Team to none and change back
- Reset device location and security setting
- Edit scheme to Ask on launch
- Deselect debug executable

XCode Managed Profile show no error, no build error, but I cannot launch it on my iPhone, I'm using XCode 10.2, my iPhone is iOS 12.2, app run normally on simulator :( please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode 9 error: "iPhone has denied the launch request"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45421179/xcode-9-error-iphone-has-denied-the-launch-request)

Comment: Its not really the same, the other one don't include `Unspecified`, and I already using Development signing, or most of the answer in there, none working, please see the list of what I have done

Comment: Did you try unplugging the phone and reconnecting it?  I know dumb, but it's worked in the past.  Even deleting the derived data and rebooting can help ... one has to love Xcode

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks, I did of course, along with restarting device multiple times as ppl said

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I have found the answer, unsure about the first time I got the issue, but I follow some instruction to delete the Apple Worldwide Certificate, turns out it won't generate automatically and you have to manually download and install again, the instruction said nothing about it though.

After drag and drop it to keychain, clean and rebuild everything worked again.

Comment: Even this doen't Helped me !

Comment: 8 years later This saved us. My Developer spent a week not understanding why nothing would deploy on the iPhone. I started investigating and within 2 hours found this and it solved the problem.

Comment: So, I had the 'Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority' in my login keychain AND in the system keychain. I had to delete both for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

I had solve this problem by set the certificate in the keychain trust system default.I set always trust

Answer (score 0):

Did you try changing the build configuration from either debug to release or vice versa?

Comment: Yes, both can't seems to launch the app

Comment: I use to have to this problem. I waited a couple days after I deleted my old dev profile and got a new one

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by going to my iPhone settings, then selected General, then Device management- Apple Development and then selected Trust.