# Unable to debug my xamarin forms app on iphone device

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a Xamarin.Forms app. It works great on Android Emulator and Android Devices, It also works on iPhone Simulator but I have not been able to get it to work on a physical iPhone Device. I have attached my output log below.

```
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
The app myapp.iOS is already deployed on mkimonos’s iPhone
Launching...
Using Xcode 11.1 found in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
Xamarin.Hosting: Xamarin.Hosting
Xamarin.Hosting:     Version: 3064e2c463 (d16-3)
Xamarin.Hosting:     Xcode: /Applications/Xcode.app
Xamarin.Hosting:     Xcode Version: 11.1
Xamarin.Hosting:     Verbosity: 1
Xamarin.Hosting: Loaded /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/DVTFoundation
Xamarin.Hosting: Loaded /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTiPhoneSimulatorRemoteClient.framework/DVTiPhoneSimulatorRemoteClient
Xamarin.Hosting: Loaded /Library/Developer/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework/CoreSimulator
Xamarin.Hosting: Loaded /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DTDeviceKitBase.framework/DTDeviceKitBase
Xamarin.Hosting: Loaded /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/DVTKit
Xamarin.Hosting: Loaded /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DTDeviceKit.framework/DTDeviceKit
Xamarin.Hosting: Loaded /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DTXConnectionServices.framework/DTXConnectionServices
Xamarin.Hosting: Loaded /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTSourceControl.framework/DVTSourceControl
Xamarin.Hosting: Loaded /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTServices.framework/DVTServices
Xamarin.Hosting: Loaded /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTPortal.framework/DVTPortal
Xamarin.Hosting: Loaded /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTDocumentation.framework/DVTDocumentation
Xamarin.Hosting: Loaded /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTAnalyticsClient.framework/DVTAnalyticsClient
Xamarin.Hosting: Loaded /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTAnalytics.framework/DVTAnalytics
Xamarin.Hosting: Loaded /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/SourceKit.framework/SourceKit
Xamarin.Hosting: Loaded /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEFoundation.framework/IDEFoundation
Xamarin.Hosting: Loaded /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/IDEProducts.framework/IDEProducts
Xamarin.Hosting: Loaded /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DTGraphKit.framework/DTGraphKit
Xamarin.Hosting: Loaded /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTDeveloperModeHelper.framework/DVTDeveloperModeHelper
Xamarin.Hosting: Loaded /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEKit.framework/IDEKit
Xamarin.Hosting: Loaded /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IBFoundation.framework/IBFoundation
Xamarin.Hosting: Loaded /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IBAutolayoutFoundation.framework/IBAutolayoutFoundation
Xamarin.Hosting: Loaded /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DebugHierarchyFoundation.framework/DebugHierarchyFoundation
Xamarin.Hosting: Loaded /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DebugHierarchyKit.framework/DebugHierarchyKit
Xamarin.Hosting: Loaded Xcode plugins successfully.
Xamarin.Hosting: Device discovery started
Xamarin.Hosting: Device discovery event: Connected (63ba7f3b7fe2bcd6c40d475d75305bc223062f63)
Xamarin.Hosting: Connected to mkimonos???s iPhone (63ba7f3b7fe2bcd6c40d475d75305bc223062f63) in 00:00:00.0022729
Xamarin.Hosting: Connecting to 'mkimonos???s iPhone', token is 0x7fc348dd3a50
Xamarin.Hosting: Connected to 'mkimonos???s iPhone'
Xamarin.Hosting: Mounting developer image on 'mkimonos???s iPhone'
Xamarin.Hosting: Mounted developer image on 'mkimonos???s iPhone'
warning MT1043: Failed to launch the application using the instruments service. Will try launching the app using gdb service.
Launching 'com.mycompany.myapp' on the device 'mkimonos???s iPhone'
Launching /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EE713368-51AD-46E7-9DEA-86F339DFE26E/myapp.iOS.app -monodevelop-port 10000 -connection-mode usb
Xamarin.Hosting: Sending command: $A192,0,2f707269766174652f7661722f636f6e7461696e6572732f42756e646c652f4170706c69636174696f6e2f45453731333336382d353141442d343645372d394445412d3836463333394446453236452f53616c65734170702e694f532e617070,34,1,2d6d6f6e6f646576656c6f702d706f7274,10,2,3130303030,32,3,2d636f6e6e656374696f6e2d6d6f6465,6,4,757362#81
Xamarin.Hosting: Received command: OK
Xamarin.Hosting: Sending command: $qLaunchSuccess#a5
Xamarin.Hosting: Received command: EUnspecified


The app has been terminated.
Launch failed. The app 'myapp.iOS' could not be launched on 'mkimonos’s iPhone'. Error: error MT1007: Failed to launch the application '/Users/sedev/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/myapp.iOS/f5f8a43c46ecffa0b819bda005d93907/bin/iPhone/Debug/myapp.iOS.app' on the device 'mkimonos???s iPhone': Failed to launch the application 'com.mycompany.myapp' on the device 'mkimonos???s iPhone': Application failed to launch: EUnspecified. You can still launch the application manually by tapping on it.. Please check the logs for more details.
The app has been terminated.
```

**---Log----**

```
Xamarin.Messaging.Client.MessagingClient|Error|0|An error occurred on the receiver while executing a post for topic xvs/idb/16.3.0.275/launch-app and client vs16132oolad
Xamarin.Messaging.Exceptions.MessagingRemoteException: An error occurred on client IDB1630275 while executing a reply for topic xvs/idb/16.3.0.275/launch-app ---> Xamarin.Messaging.Exceptions.MonotouchException: error MT1007: Failed to launch the application '/Users/sedev/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/myapp.iOS/f5f8a43c46ecffa0b819bda005d93907/bin/iPhone/Debug/myapp.iOS.app' on the device 'mkimonos???s iPhone': Failed to launch the application 'com.mycompany.myapp' on the device 'mkimonos???s iPhone': Application failed to launch: EUnspecified. You can still launch the application manually by tapping on it.
  at Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.MTouch.RunAsync (System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[T] parameters, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken, System.Func`2[T,TResult] exitCondition, Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.MTouchProcessType processType, System.Action`1[T] reportProgress, System.Action`1[T] handleOutput) [0x00255] in <d8be3adffa5b48778dec947885285f36>:0 
  at Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.MTouch.LaunchAsync (Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.Contracts.AppInfo appInfo, Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.Contracts.Simulator simulator, System.Boolean debugging, System.Int32 port, System.Action`1[T] reportProgress) [0x001d0] in <d8be3adffa5b48778dec947885285f36>:0 
  at Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.LaunchAppMessageHandler.RunMTouchAsync (Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.Contracts.LaunchAppMessage message, System.Int32 port) [0x001a8] in <d8be3adffa5b48778dec947885285f36>:0 
  at Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.LaunchAppMessageHandler.ExecuteOnPhysicalDeviceWithoutAssetsAsync (Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.Contracts.LaunchAppMessage message) [0x00091] in <d8be3adffa5b48778dec947885285f36>:0 
  at Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.LaunchAppMessageHandler.ExecuteOnPhysicalDeviceAsync (Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.Contracts.LaunchAppMessage message) [0x0019b] in <d8be3adffa5b48778dec947885285f36>:0 
  at Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.LaunchAppMessageHandler.ExecuteAsync (Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.Contracts.LaunchAppMessage message) [0x00104] in <d8be3adffa5b48778dec947885285f36>:0 
  at Xamarin.Messaging.Client.RequestHandler`2[TMessage,TResult].HandleAsync (TMessage message) [0x0010e] in <7a4eb22bf69741c1ae63de89827712f0>:0 
  at Xamarin.Messaging.Client.MessageHandlerManager+<>c__DisplayClass17_1`2[TMessage,TResult].<RegisterHandlerAsync>b__2 () [0x00084] in <7a4eb22bf69741c1ae63de89827712f0>:0 
  at Xamarin.Messaging.Client.MessagingClient.ReplyAsync[TRequest,TResponse] (Xamarin.Messaging.Client.IRequest`1[T] request, Xamarin.Messaging.MessagePriority priority, System.Func`1[TResult] replyFunctionAsync) [0x000c5] in <7a4eb22bf69741c1ae63de89827712f0>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Xamarin.Messaging.Client.MessagingClient.<PostAsync>d__23`2.MoveNext() in E:\A\_work\171\s\External\messaging\src\Xamarin.Messaging.Client\MessagingClient.cs:line 183
Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.IdbClient|Error|0|Launch failed. The app 'myapp.iOS' could not be launched on 'mkimonos’s iPhone'. Error: error MT1007: Failed to launch the application '/Users/sedev/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/myapp.iOS/f5f8a43c46ecffa0b819bda005d93907/bin/iPhone/Debug/myapp.iOS.app' on the device 'mkimonos???s iPhone': Failed to launch the application 'com.mycompany.myapp' on the device 'mkimonos???s iPhone': Application failed to launch: EUnspecified. You can still launch the application manually by tapping on it.. Please check the logs for more details.
Xamarin.Messaging.Exceptions.MonotouchException: error MT1007: Failed to launch the application '/Users/sedev/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/myapp.iOS/f5f8a43c46ecffa0b819bda005d93907/bin/iPhone/Debug/myapp.iOS.app' on the device 'mkimonos???s iPhone': Failed to launch the application 'com.mycompany.myapp' on the device 'mkimonos???s iPhone': Application failed to launch: EUnspecified. You can still launch the application manually by tapping on it.
  at Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.MTouch.RunAsync (System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[T] parameters, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken, System.Func`2[T,TResult] exitCondition, Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.MTouchProcessType processType, System.Action`1[T] reportProgress, System.Action`1[T] handleOutput) [0x00255] in <d8be3adffa5b48778dec947885285f36>:0 
  at Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.MTouch.LaunchAsync (Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.Contracts.AppInfo appInfo, Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.Contracts.Simulator simulator, System.Boolean debugging, System.Int32 port, System.Action`1[T] reportProgress) [0x001d0] in <d8be3adffa5b48778dec947885285f36>:0 
  at Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.LaunchAppMessageHandler.RunMTouchAsync (Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.Contracts.LaunchAppMessage message, System.Int32 port) [0x001a8] in <d8be3adffa5b48778dec947885285f36>:0 
  at Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.LaunchAppMessageHandler.ExecuteOnPhysicalDeviceWithoutAssetsAsync (Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.Contracts.LaunchAppMessage message) [0x00091] in <d8be3adffa5b48778dec947885285f36>:0 
  at Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.LaunchAppMessageHandler.ExecuteOnPhysicalDeviceAsync (Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.Contracts.LaunchAppMessage message) [0x0019b] in <d8be3adffa5b48778dec947885285f36>:0 
  at Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.LaunchAppMessageHandler.ExecuteAsync (Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.Contracts.LaunchAppMessage message) [0x00104] in <d8be3adffa5b48778dec947885285f36>:0 
  at Xamarin.Messaging.Client.RequestHandler`2[TMessage,TResult].HandleAsync (TMessage message) [0x0010e] in <7a4eb22bf69741c1ae63de89827712f0>:0 
  at Xamarin.Messaging.Client.MessageHandlerManager+<>c__DisplayClass17_1`2[TMessage,TResult].<RegisterHandlerAsync>b__2 () [0x00084] in <7a4eb22bf69741c1ae63de89827712f0>:0 
  at Xamarin.Messaging.Client.MessagingClient.ReplyAsync[TRequest,TResponse] (Xamarin.Messaging.Client.IRequest`1[T] request, Xamarin.Messaging.MessagePriority priority, System.Func`1[TResult] replyFunctionAsync) [0x000c5] in <7a4eb22bf69741c1ae63de89827712f0>:0
```

---

**I created a new project and created a new provisioning profile to sign it. 
I added "-v -v -v -v" mtouch arguments in .iOS properties.
I have attached the build output log and debug log to provide more details.**

***Note: this issue also exists for a new xamarin forms app straight from the template***

**Build Log**

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: TestXamarinApp, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>TestXamarinApp -> C:\Users\ooladejo\source\repos\TestXamarinApp\TestXamarinApp\TestXamarinApp\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\TestXamarinApp.dll
2>------ Rebuild All started: Project: TestXamarinApp.iOS, Configuration: Debug iPhone ------
2>  Executing SayHello Task to establish a connection to a Mac Server. 
2>                           Properties: SessionId=b2d95c84baf5210e5ace46d00f31f3f1, 
2>                              ServerPort=53786, 
2>                              ServerAddress=182.1.1.1, 
2>                              ServerUser=Sedev, 
2>                              ServerPassword=, 
2>                              SSHKey=, 
2>                              SSHPassPhrase=,
2>                              AppName=TestXamarinApp.iOS,
2>                              ContinueOnDisconnected=False
2>  Connecting to Mac server 182.1.1.1...
2>  Executing SayHello Task to establish a connection to a Mac Server. 
2>                           Properties: SessionId=b2d95c84baf5210e5ace46d00f31f3f1, 
2>                              ServerPort=53786, 
2>                              ServerAddress=182.1.1.1, 
2>                              ServerUser=Sedev, 
2>                              ServerPassword=, 
2>                              SSHKey=, 
2>                              SSHPassPhrase=,
2>                              AppName=TestXamarinApp.iOS,
2>                              ContinueOnDisconnected=False
2>  Connecting to Mac server 182.1.1.1...
2>  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/pngcrush -q -iphone -f 0 Resources/tab_about.png obj/iPhone/Debug/optimized/tab_about.png 
2>  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/pngcrush -q -iphone -f 0 "Resources/tab_about@2x.png" "obj/iPhone/Debug/optimized/tab_about@2x.png" 
2>  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/pngcrush -q -iphone -f 0 "Resources/tab_about@3x.png" "obj/iPhone/Debug/optimized/tab_about@3x.png" 
2>  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/pngcrush -q -iphone -f 0 Resources/tab_feed.png obj/iPhone/Debug/optimized/tab_feed.png 
2>  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/pngcrush -q -iphone -f 0 "Resources/tab_feed@2x.png" "obj/iPhone/Debug/optimized/tab_feed@2x.png" 
2>  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/pngcrush -q -iphone -f 0 "Resources/tab_feed@3x.png" "obj/iPhone/Debug/optimized/tab_feed@3x.png" 
2>  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/pngcrush -q -iphone -f 0 Resources/xamarin_logo.png obj/iPhone/Debug/optimized/xamarin_logo.png 
2>  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/pngcrush -q -iphone -f 0 "Resources/xamarin_logo@2x.png" "obj/iPhone/Debug/optimized/xamarin_logo@2x.png" 
2>  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/pngcrush -q -iphone -f 0 "Resources/xamarin_logo@3x.png" "obj/iPhone/Debug/optimized/xamarin_logo@3x.png" 
2>  No way to resolve conflict between "System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" and "System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e". Choosing "System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" arbitrarily.
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2106,5): warning MSB3277: Found conflicts between different versions of "System.Numerics" that could not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed.
2>  TestXamarinApp.iOS -> C:\Users\ooladejo\source\repos\TestXamarinApp\TestXamarinApp\TestXamarinApp.iOS\bin\iPhone\Debug\TestXamarinApp.iOS.exe
2>  Detected signing identity:
2>    Code Signing Key: "iPhone Developer: Marios Kimonos (************)" (182CD0EEF*************************)
2>    Provisioning Profile: "Test App Profile" (23666d10******************************)
2>    Bundle Id: com.testdomain.testxamarinapp
2>    App Id: 27R4SA28KL.com.testdomain.testxamarinapp
2>  /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/bin/mtouch @/Users/sedev/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/TestXamarinApp.iOS/b2d95c84baf5210e5ace46d00f31f3f1/obj/iPhone/Debug/response-file.rsp -v -v -v -v 
2>  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/dsymutil -t 4 -z -o bin/iPhone/Debug/TestXamarinApp.iOS.app.dSYM bin/iPhone/Debug/TestXamarinApp.iOS.app/TestXamarinApp.iOS 
2>  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/strip -i -s obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-symbols.list bin/iPhone/Debug/TestXamarinApp.iOS.app/TestXamarinApp.iOS 
2>  /usr/bin/mdimport bin/iPhone/Debug/TestXamarinApp.iOS.app/../ 
2>  /usr/bin/codesign --verify -vvvv -R='anchor apple generic and certificate 1[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.2.1] exists and (certificate leaf[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.2] exists or certificate leaf[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.4] exists)' bin/iPhone/Debug/TestXamarinApp.iOS.app 
========== Rebuild All: 2 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

**Debug Log**

```
Xamarin.Messaging.Client.MessagingClient|Error|0|An error occurred on the receiver while executing a post for topic xvs/idb/16.3.0.277/launch-app and client vs2980oolad
Xamarin.Messaging.Exceptions.MessagingRemoteException: An error occurred on client IDB1630277 while executing a reply for topic xvs/idb/16.3.0.277/launch-app ---> Xamarin.Messaging.Exceptions.MonotouchException: error MT1007: Failed to launch the application '/Users/sedev/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/TestXamarinApp.iOS/b2d95c84baf5210e5ace46d00f31f3f1/bin/iPhone/Debug/TestXamarinApp.iOS.app' on the device 'mkimonos???s iPhone': Failed to launch the application 'com.testdomain.testxamarinapp' on the device 'mkimonos???s iPhone': Application failed to launch: EUnspecified. You can still launch the application manually by tapping on it.
  at Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.MTouch.RunAsync (System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[T] parameters, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken, System.Func`2[T,TResult] exitCondition, Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.MTouchProcessType processType, System.Action`1[T] reportProgress, System.Action`1[T] handleOutput) [0x00255] in <1d6787a7a52349bd95d3beb793a73b9d>:0 
  at Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.MTouch.LaunchAsync (Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.Contracts.AppInfo appInfo, Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.Contracts.Simulator simulator, System.Boolean debugging, System.Int32 port, System.Action`1[T] reportProgress) [0x001d0] in <1d6787a7a52349bd95d3beb793a73b9d>:0 
  at Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.LaunchAppMessageHandler.RunMTouchAsync (Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.Contracts.LaunchAppMessage message, System.Int32 port) [0x001a8] in <1d6787a7a52349bd95d3beb793a73b9d>:0 
  at Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.LaunchAppMessageHandler.ExecuteOnPhysicalDeviceWithoutAssetsAsync (Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.Contracts.LaunchAppMessage message) [0x00091] in <1d6787a7a52349bd95d3beb793a73b9d>:0 
  at Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.LaunchAppMessageHandler.ExecuteOnPhysicalDeviceAsync (Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.Contracts.LaunchAppMessage message) [0x0019b] in <1d6787a7a52349bd95d3beb793a73b9d>:0 
  at Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.LaunchAppMessageHandler.ExecuteAsync (Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.Contracts.LaunchAppMessage message) [0x00104] in <1d6787a7a52349bd95d3beb793a73b9d>:0 
  at Xamarin.Messaging.Client.RequestHandler`2[TMessage,TResult].HandleAsync (TMessage message) [0x0010e] in <8eeac389ee7c4078bb43eca6a43b5be2>:0 
  at Xamarin.Messaging.Client.MessageHandlerManager+<>c__DisplayClass17_1`2[TMessage,TResult].<RegisterHandlerAsync>b__2 () [0x00084] in <8eeac389ee7c4078bb43eca6a43b5be2>:0 
  at Xamarin.Messaging.Client.MessagingClient.ReplyAsync[TRequest,TResponse] (Xamarin.Messaging.Client.IRequest`1[T] request, Xamarin.Messaging.MessagePriority priority, System.Func`1[TResult] replyFunctionAsync) [0x000c5] in <8eeac389ee7c4078bb43eca6a43b5be2>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Xamarin.Messaging.Client.MessagingClient.<PostAsync>d__23`2.MoveNext() in E:\A\_work\275\s\External\messaging\src\Xamarin.Messaging.Client\MessagingClient.cs:line 183
Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.IdbClient|Error|0|Launch failed. The app 'TestXamarinApp.iOS' could not be launched on 'mkimonos’s iPhone'. Error: error MT1007: Failed to launch the application '/Users/sedev/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/TestXamarinApp.iOS/b2d95c84baf5210e5ace46d00f31f3f1/bin/iPhone/Debug/TestXamarinApp.iOS.app' on the device 'mkimonos???s iPhone': Failed to launch the application 'com.testdomain.testxamarinapp' on the device 'mkimonos???s iPhone': Application failed to launch: EUnspecified. You can still launch the application manually by tapping on it.. Please check the logs for more details.
Xamarin.Messaging.Exceptions.MonotouchException: error MT1007: Failed to launch the application '/Users/sedev/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/TestXamarinApp.iOS/b2d95c84baf5210e5ace46d00f31f3f1/bin/iPhone/Debug/TestXamarinApp.iOS.app' on the device 'mkimonos???s iPhone': Failed to launch the application 'com.testdomain.testxamarinapp' on the device 'mkimonos???s iPhone': Application failed to launch: EUnspecified. You can still launch the application manually by tapping on it.
  at Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.MTouch.RunAsync (System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[T] parameters, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken, System.Func`2[T,TResult] exitCondition, Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.MTouchProcessType processType, System.Action`1[T] reportProgress, System.Action`1[T] handleOutput) [0x00255] in <1d6787a7a52349bd95d3beb793a73b9d>:0 
  at Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.MTouch.LaunchAsync (Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.Contracts.AppInfo appInfo, Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.Contracts.Simulator simulator, System.Boolean debugging, System.Int32 port, System.Action`1[T] reportProgress) [0x001d0] in <1d6787a7a52349bd95d3beb793a73b9d>:0 
  at Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.LaunchAppMessageHandler.RunMTouchAsync (Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.Contracts.LaunchAppMessage message, System.Int32 port) [0x001a8] in <1d6787a7a52349bd95d3beb793a73b9d>:0 
  at Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.LaunchAppMessageHandler.ExecuteOnPhysicalDeviceWithoutAssetsAsync (Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.Contracts.LaunchAppMessage message) [0x00091] in <1d6787a7a52349bd95d3beb793a73b9d>:0 
  at Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.LaunchAppMessageHandler.ExecuteOnPhysicalDeviceAsync (Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.Contracts.LaunchAppMessage message) [0x0019b] in <1d6787a7a52349bd95d3beb793a73b9d>:0 
  at Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.LaunchAppMessageHandler.ExecuteAsync (Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.Contracts.LaunchAppMessage message) [0x00104] in <1d6787a7a52349bd95d3beb793a73b9d>:0 
  at Xamarin.Messaging.Client.RequestHandler`2[TMessage,TResult].HandleAsync (TMessage message) [0x0010e] in <8eeac389ee7c4078bb43eca6a43b5be2>:0 
  at Xamarin.Messaging.Client.MessageHandlerManager+<>c__DisplayClass17_1`2[TMessage,TResult].<RegisterHandlerAsync>b__2 () [0x00084] in <8eeac389ee7c4078bb43eca6a43b5be2>:0 
  at Xamarin.Messaging.Client.MessagingClient.ReplyAsync[TRequest,TResponse] (Xamarin.Messaging.Client.IRequest`1[T] request, Xamarin.Messaging.MessagePriority priority, System.Func`1[TResult] replyFunctionAsync) [0x000c5] in <8eeac389ee7c4078bb43eca6a43b5be2>:0
```

Comment: It's pretty common and happens to a lot of people. The app output says `Please check the logs for more details`, could you please check your Device Logs and share those?

Comment: You already have provisioning profile for tests in real devices?

Comment: @Saamer I have shared the log

Comment: @GuilhermeNimer Yes i do

Comment: Have you tried to 1) Remove application from device 2) Reboot the device 3) Quit Visual Studio 4) Clean up all the temporary files and folders, bin and obj folder and then retry?

Comment: @Saamer Yes i did that . I even deleted the profile, app id and recreated everything from scratch but still same result

Comment: @OlaleyeOladejo add "-v -v -v -v" mtouch arguments in .iOS properties, then put the log here again

Comment: While the Xamarin iOS MT1007 error can mean many things, in this case it boils down to trust.try this :1. On your iPhone, navigate to Settings -> General -> Device Management.2.Within Device Management, you should see your developer provisioning profile, click it.3.Trust the developer profile.

Comment: @GuilhermeNimer I created a new project and added "-v -v -v -v" mtouch arguments in .iOS properties . kindly see log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting the Apple Worldwide Certificate on the Mac used for building solved it.

See solution here [iPhone has denied the launch request Unspecified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55591220/iphone-has-denied-the-launch-request-unspecified)

Answer (score -1):

You are missing [Provisioning Profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/)

Also you need to add the device into [Developer portal](https://developer.apple.com/) in order to run it on device.

Comment: I did all that. I have a provisioning profile, the app is signed, the device is on my developer portal and also linked to my provisioning profile

Comment: @OlaleyeOladejo What version of ios does it run? I hope you have Trusted the device. what happens when when you manually tap on app to open.?

Comment: 12.4.2 iphone 6. yes i trusted the device .When i tap on it, it opens and closes immediately. just a flash