# iPhone has denied the launch request. Internal launch error: process launch failed: Unspecified

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, launching-application

I tried all the possible [solutions in the SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45421179/xcode-9-error-iphone-has-denied-the-launch-request), but none of them giving legit solution. Can anyone figure what's the root cause of this error ? Is the problem with iPhone or Xcode or Keychain ?

Error in Debug mode in Xcode 11 targeted iPhone SE:

> Could not launch "My App xyz"  has denied the launch request.
>   Internal launch error: process launch failed: Unspecified

[image: e S]

Comment: try Quit Xcode -> Restart -> Clean -> Run

Comment: @Deepak No luck.. Cleaned (Cmd+Shik+Alrt+K) > Restarted Xcode + iPhone + Mac.

Comment: This is happening on every Xcode Projects in my System.

Comment: Some *Fishy on Keychain* is what I think !!

Answer (score 4):

```
Open your target -> Signing and Capabilities->Set your development certificate
```

In my case i was using **distribution** profile instead of **development** one.

Answer (score 1):

For the iPhone software version 13.5, I had to trust the Developer App from the Device Management

**Settings > General > Device Management > Select the Apple Development Account you want to Trust**

Comment: I didnt find this settings on my phone . could you please send a screen shot where it is residing

Answer (score 0):

Clear project -> Unplug iPhone -> Restart Xcode -> Plug iPhone again helped me as well.

Xcode 11.1 (11A1027) & iPhone 7 iOS 13.1.3

Comment: However, same project if I open in Another User account in the system. it works .

Answer (score 0):

You can make it work either with manual or automatic signing, you just need to disable "Debug executable" on your Xcode build scheme:

[image: Disable "Debug executable" on Xcode build scheme]